# MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL does not work on SGS2 (call recording)

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Using mediarecorder to record calls, with setting the audio source to

MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL

does not work on Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 2.3.4), in the application freezes and no recording is created (VOICE_UPLINK/VOICE_DOWNLINK both work, but only record up/downlink, not both party voice).

However, e.g. the CallRecorder application (from Android Market) does work (recording both party voices). So it's possible.

How is it done?

Comment: try after setting mediasoure to mic

Comment: MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC works, same as VOICE_UPLINK, VOICE_DOWNLINK, but doesn't record both party voice (only the mic).

Comment: try to use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to record through `AudioSource.CAMCORDER` on a Galaxy S2, but I have the same issue; I get no samples.  Actually, I tried to have two audio sources, `.MIC` and `.CAMCORDER`, recording separate samples, but I guess, just like khan said, `.MIC` will probably work.